# XML validation in xml file with Eclipse

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, xml-validation, xsd-validation

I have some problens with validating my xml file. I get the error message "cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'xsi:settings'." in my xml file . To me, my code is correct, but obviously it shouldn't be..

My xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsi:settings  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/Application.xsd">
    <info>
            <Version>1.0</Version>
            <Release_date>2012-07-27</Release_date>
    </info>

    <config>
        <Betriebssystem>Windows</Betriebssystem>
        <Wildcard>%</Wildcard>
        <Errormessages>
            <View1>
                <Message1>Der neue Mitarbeiter braucht ein Geburtsdatum der Form JJJJ-MM-TT und eine nicht vorhandene Personalnummer</Message1>
                <Message2>Dem Mitarbeiter muss eine Personalnummer zugewiesen werden</Message2>
            </View1>
            <View3>
                <Message1>Sie muessen mindestens ein Kriterienfeld ausfuellen"</Message1>
                <Message2>Der Mitarbeiter braucht ein Geburtsdatum der Form JJJJ-MM-TT und eine nicht vorhandene Personalnummer</Message2>
                <Message3>Sie muessen erst einen Mitarbeiter laden</Message3>
                <Message4>Problem beim Loeschen des Mitarbeiters. Ist der Mitarbeiter in der Datenbank vorhanden?</Message4>
            </View3>
        </Errormessages>
    </config>
</xsi:settings>
```

My xsd file(has no errors):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >

 <xs:element name="settings">
 <xs:complexType>
 <xs:sequence>

 <xs:element name="info">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:float" name="Version"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:date" name="Release_date"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="config">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Betriebssystem"/>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Wildcard"/>
        <xs:element name="Errormessages">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>

              <xs:element name="View1">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Message1"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Message2"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>

              <xs:element name="View3">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Message1"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Message2"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Message3"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Message4"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>

            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>


</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Harald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your namespaces wrong. To go along, your corrected sample is shown below. First, you have to reference the XML Schema Instance namespace (below using xst prefix) and use schemaLocation instead (since you have a target namespace).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsi:settings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xst="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xst:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/Application.xsd"> 
    <info> 
        <Version>1.0</Version> 
        <Release_date>2012-07-27</Release_date> 
    </info> 
    <config> 
        <Betriebssystem>Windows</Betriebssystem> 
        <Wildcard>%</Wildcard> 
        <Errormessages> 
            <View1> 
                <Message1>Der neue Mitarbeiter braucht ein Geburtsdatum der Form JJJJ-MM-TT und eine nicht vorhandene Personalnummer</Message1> 
                <Message2>Dem Mitarbeiter muss eine Personalnummer zugewiesen werden</Message2> 
            </View1> 
            <View3> 
                <Message1>Sie muessen mindestens ein Kriterienfeld ausfuellen"</Message1> 
                <Message2>Der Mitarbeiter braucht ein Geburtsdatum der Form JJJJ-MM-TT und eine nicht vorhandene Personalnummer</Message2> 
                <Message3>Sie muessen erst einen Mitarbeiter laden</Message3> 
                <Message4>Problem beim Loeschen des Mitarbeiters. Ist der Mitarbeiter in der Datenbank vorhanden?</Message4> 
            </View3> 
        </Errormessages> 
    </config> 
</xsi:settings>
```

I am showing another example, that makes common use of prefixes. xsi is used for XML Schema instance. Nonetheless, it is arbitrary and as shown above, it can work with something else as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<settings xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <info xmlns="">
        <Version>1</Version>
        <Release_date>1900-01-01</Release_date>
    </info>
    <config xmlns="">
        <Betriebssystem>Betriebssystem1</Betriebssystem>
        <Wildcard>Wildcard1</Wildcard>
        <Errormessages>
            <View1>
                <Message1>Message11</Message1>
                <Message2>Message21</Message2>
            </View1>
            <View3>
                <Message1>Message11</Message1>
                <Message2>Message21</Message2>
                <Message3>Message31</Message3>
                <Message4>Message41</Message4>
            </View3>
        </Errormessages>
    </config>
</settings>
```

I can't but comment on the fact that in general, it is not a good thing to target the W3C XML Schema (XSD) uri (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema), nor the XML Schema Instance (XSI) uri (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance).

Comment: Than you very much @petru-gardea for the clear explanations. It works. However, i get a "s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'element' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'." error if i try to change the name of the namespaces..